# How to set color for Columnchart in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I want to render specific requests from my Application Insights as a columnchart using Log Analytics query language:

**My Query**:

```
requests
| where operation_Name == "MyOperationName" 
| render columnchart
```

**Output:**

[image: Columnchart]

I would like to have different colors for successful and unsuccessful requests.
There is already a boolean column ("success") available. How can I use that property to set specific colors?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, this is currently unsupported. The similar feedback shown [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics?query=color) and [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics/suggestions/10021779-make-it-more-meaningful-with-color-grids-and-pie-a) were shared directly with the responsible Azure feature team. I recommend navigating to the above link(s) and clicking the vote button to raise visibility and priority on this or else providing your own new feedback and suggestions to improve the product better. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Both of the links are currently broken.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set colors by using Application Insights workbooks. When creating the query there is a button for chart settings and within it look for the series settings tab.  Currently it allows setting colors and changing a result value's display label.